# How to remove hardcoded string value

Tags: apex, visualforce

Below is my controller and Visualforce page. In this i am trying to remove the Harcoded string. i am getting value in s1.Name. But from the salesforce i have to write the name like ReadyWidth only. If i Write like READYWIDTH then its not working. So any idea how can i remove this hardcoded string value and make it work with lowe and uppercase both?

Controller:-

```
Map<String, String> sp = new Map<String, String>();  

List<ServiceProgram__C> s = [SELECT  name,Length__c, Width__c from ServiceProgram__C where E_Product__c = :ci.ccrz__Product__r.id];

            sp.put(s1.Name,String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(s1.Length__c))+':'+String.valueOf(s1.Width__c));  


          }

          returnObject.put('servicePrograms', sp);
          System.debug(returnObject.get('servicePrograms'));
```

Visual Force:-

```
        else if (valChanged == 'ReadyWidth') {
          $(".jsRollProductInfo").removeClass("hidden");
          $(".jsMasterPunch").addClass("hidden");
          $(".jsMasterWind").addClass("hidden");

          var allowances = $("#ReadyWidth").val();
          var parts = allowances.split(":");
          var lengths = parts[0].split(",");
          var widths = parts[1].split(",");
          $('#rollLengthText').addClass("hidden");              
          $('#rollLengthDD').removeClass("hidden");
          $('#rollLengthDD').empty();
          $.each(lengths, function (i, item) {
                            $('#rollLengthDD').append($('<option>', { 
                                value: item,
                                text : item 
                            }));
                        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom label in your Org and then refer that label in your VF page using  `$Label.CustomLabel` where **customlabel** is the label you created.

You can refer the same custom label in Apex using `System.Label.CustomLabel`

You can ignore the Case using `String.equalsIgnoreCase("String")`

Please refer [How to use Custom Labels in Visualforce page and Apex Class](http://www.infallibletechie.com/2012/11/how-to-use-custom-labels-in-visualforce.html)
for more details